# How can I find the missing data from the downloaded bulk TRMM data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, netcdf, download, missing-data

I have downloaded TRMM daily precipitation estimates for Indian Sub-continent from 1988 to present. I see that there are a lot of missing data days. I was wondering how can I possibly detect the daily missing TRMM files automatically without manually skimming through the downloaded data? Is there any tool/function/code that I can use to do this? I need to use the complete time-series as an input to a hydrological model. And in order to fill the missing data I need to know the exact days when it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need TRMM data there is a new QGIS plugin that allows you to download the 3B42 product. You can download the original data, with a 3 hours frequency, but you can also aggregate it in daily layers. The data is available from January 1st 1998 to July 31st 2015. You can browse the plugin page here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geobricks_qgis_plugin_trmm/